# Migrating from tomcat to tc server - receiving java.sql.SQLException on startup

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I'm receiving below error when I start tcServer. I do not receive this error on standalone version of tomcat. Is there extra config I need to add for tcServer ?

WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112) at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146) at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387) at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:441) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:165) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35) at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801) at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:277) at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182) at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:699) at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:631) at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:485) at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.(ConnectionPool.java:143) at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116) at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103) at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:539) at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:237) at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:140) at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:304) at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:793) at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140) at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:781) at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153) at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1028) at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:637) at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:238) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:747) at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289) at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best I can tell from that dump you've got a bad connection string, or an incorrectly configured TNSNAMES.ORA file.